# QuickBooks reports invalid certificate for Excel AddIn written in C# using QBXML

Tags: excel, vsto, quickbooks

I believe the problem is related to the latest release of Office 365, or of WinX. For some reason the information needed by QuickBooks to find the application's certificate related information is not being passed along from the Office code.

I wrote a console application linked to the same libraries used for my AddIn and it was able to connect to QB. Other users of my AddIn are still able to use it. I found that they were running an older release of Office365, 16.0.8229.2091 or earlier. The desktop that is failing is running Office365, 16.0.9229.2103 (previously I had this as .2013 instead of the correct version .2103). When I look at the Properties for the Integrated Application, the console version correctly shows the Developed By: and Developer identity verified by: information. When I do the same for the AddIn, it shows Unknown for the Developed By: and it shows: This application does not have a certificate. QuickBooks cannot determine the developer's identity.

Users have been running my AddIn for about two years now. I'm using the latest version of the QBXMLRP along with Visual Studio 2015 and version 4.5.2 of the .NET Framework. I used the same process to generate the test certificate and both assemblies were signed with sha256.

To the best of my knowledge, the program broke when the latest version of Office365 was installed. That being said, it could be an issue related to the latest patch of Windows and that information I do not have. However, given that other workstations can run the AddIn and have earlier versions of Office365, I'm thinking that's a pretty good indicator. And that I was able to get a console app to run, but the AddIn fails to access QuickBooks. It does load in Excel just fine, but it is not able to connect with QB.

Comment: FYI - I just tried the same AddIn on my laptop, after updating my Office365 to version 16.0.7766.2099 and it still works. Also, I'm running Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - en-us while my client is running Office 365 Business - en-us. I wonder if it has something to do with the ProPlus vs. Business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this issue on the [QB forum](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f00004vS1zjCAC/quickbooks-reports-invalid-certificate-for-excel-addin-written-in-c-using-qbxml) and received the answer. It appears that Microsoft released an update of its Office365 Business software that caused the problem. They have since released a subsequent update that should provide remedy.

I've included a link for your convenience.

**Good news, the problem WAS resolved by installing the latest update for Office365! Whew!! That was a real pain in the butt. A special thank you to William Lorfing at the Intuit Developer Group for keeping tabs on this problem and alerting others to the solution.**